# Load. XIB in a class

Tags: c#, iphone, uitableview, xamarin.ios, nib

How do I load a. XIB by clicking on the row of table view?
This example below is part of a class, as I fario alert the loading of this class?

```
public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    tableView.DeselectRow (indexPath, true);

    //this.PresentModalViewController(home,true);
}
```

Comment: Why on earth are you using what look like plain C methods? Use the objective-c methods in UITableViewController.

Comment: his post is tagged MonoTouch - that is C#, not Obj-C

Comment: Ah sorry, I wasn't aware you could program for iPhone without using Obj-C

Comment: The class is separated from the rest of the code, I can not use the
this.PresentModalViewController(home,true);

Answer (score 0):

There's not many details in your question and comments...

If you `override` the `RowSelected` method then you're likely inheriting a new type from `UITableViewSource` right ? If so then you should make its constructor keep a reference to the `UITableViewController` and use this reference to call `PresentModalViewController` later.

E.g.

```
public class MyTableViewSource : UITableViewSource {

    UITableViewController ctrl;

    public MyTableViewSource (UITableViewController c)
    {
        ctrl = c;
    }

    public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        tableView.DeselectRow (indexPath, true);
        var home = new UIViewController ("YouNibName", null); // default bundle
        ctrl.PresentModalViewController (home, true);
    }
}
```

note: I used `UIViewController` but you likely already have a type defined for your NIB.

Comment: Error:MonoTouch.UIKit.UITableView' does not contain a definition for `PresentModalViewController' and no extension method

Comment: **I am inheriting the UITableViewSource.**

Comment: Same pattern would apply for `UITableViewSource` and you should pass the `UITableViewController` (not the view itself). I'll update the code sample...